# Odd results in get_the_terms vs wp_get_post_terms

Tags: categories

I'm trying to make a breadcrumb function and I nearly have it don but one small snag...

When I use:

```
$categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
```

I get back an array of categories to use in a loop, etc. Only problem is that it's in alphabetical order. (I want it in hierarchical order.)

After some digging, I saw one alternative was to use wp_get_post_terms(), but I must be missing something because when I use this:

```
$categories = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', array( 'orderby' => 'term_id' ) );
```

I get an empty array returned.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference between the two is that `wp_get_post_terms` is not cached and always goes straight to the database, in fact `get_the_terms` uses the same API internally, `wp_get_post_terms` is a wrapper around `wp_get_object_terms`, which is also used by get_the_terms but with caching and fewer configurable options.

However, this is an X Y question. You shouldn't have asked how to solve your solution with the empty return value, but instead how to solve your problem, aka:

> I get back an array of categories to use in a loop, etc. Only problem is that it's in alphabetical order. (I want it in hierarchical order.)

**There is no such thing as hierarchical order in these APIs.**

*To do this you will need to add a processing step* or loops to iterate over the list of terms. e.g. for each term, if it has no parent, display it then loop over all terms in a nested loop displaying those that have this term as their parent, etc. Recursion will be needed if you want more than one layer of depth.

For performance reasons you should use `get_the_terms`.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I did do some preliminary digging before posting but "hierarchical" was definitely a poor choice of wording on this. In the back of my mind I was figuring a recursive solution would end up being the way to go. Unfortunately I do them once in a blue moon and they're one of my big hurdles. Spent a few hours working through it that way but it will definitely be a matter of pecking away at it over time. Fingers crossed!